# Spring Security Oauth2: Success Logout in Tomcat but Cannot Logout in Glashfish

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am just beginner in Spring Security Oauth2.
I have Authorization Server and Resource Server (separated).
The flow that I used is Authorization Code. And I have success to login tho the Authorization Server, get the code, and then get the accessToken.
Then, I have a problem when I want to logout. When I deploy the Authorization Server in Apache Tomcat, it can call 'j_spring_security_logout' but when I deploy in Glashfish, it cant.

Here my security config:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false);

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.jsp").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.jsp")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler);
}
```

Here my logouthandler:

```
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String token=req.getParameter("token");
    if(token != null){
        consumerTokenServices.revokeToken(token);
    }
    String redirect = req.getParameter("redirect");
    if(redirect != null){
        res.sendRedirect(redirect);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "can't" what do you mean? What happens when you try?

Comment: It not work. The server cannot open the url (the mapping not found)

Comment: It's the same war file?

Comment: Yes, same file.
And I and my friends just solve the problem.
The problem because my glassfish cannot handle the crsf protection, so we make the crsf handler
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "cannot handle"?

Comment: It just refuse the csrf. I don't know why. I use Tomcat and my friend use Glassfish. He said that he make csrf handler so the glassfish accept the csrf setting.

Comment: Must be something to do with the session storage. I'm quite surprised it doesn't work (maybe not vanilla glassfish).